# Supporting multiple domains under one mailserver

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email-server

I'm running my own Ubuntu server using Postfix to serve my email needs for a certain domain (let's call it `domain.com`). The mailserver does not have a mailbox, it forwards received emails to assigned receivers for each `domain.com` address. To send out emails, users will have to connect with the mailserver at `mail.domain.com` using an interface such as Gmail, and use `mail.domain.com` as a mail relay.

Currently, `mail.domain.com` only supports sending of emails from `domain.com`, but I'm thinking of also sending emails out from `example.com` using `mail.domain.com`. I currently have an SPF record and DMARC record for `domain.com`, as well as a DKIM key for `mail.domain.com` (with OpenDKIM set up at the back). For `example.com`, if i set its MX to `mail.domain.com`, I will only need an SPF and a DMARC DNS record for it, correct? Since DKIM (and all other mailserver config-related stuff like rDNS) will be handled by `mail.domain.com`.

I apologise if I am missing out any information. I'm pretty new to this mailserver business, and I just want to make sure all the necessary records for email policy are set for `example.com` so that its emails don't get marked as spam.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I have not time now for answer (I will do later if nobody else will not do it ;-)). At this moment I will write at least hint as a comment what to look for...
- virtual_alias_maps
- virtual_mailbox_domains
- virtual_mailbox_maps

Comment: Did you check out https://workaround.org/ispmail? It is a very detailed and step-by-step tutorial explaining how to set up mail servers for multiple domains. It's not the clear-cut answer you're looking for but it will hopefully give you a better understanding of mailservers in general.